# Swift Uint32 Recognizing All Even Numbers as the Same

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am using SpriteKit in Swift and have the following situation:

- I construct a struct in the superclass level that has a list of UInt32s to represent the various bitmasks that I need to establish types of physics bodies. (This is stupid because struct properties cannot be overridden in the subclass. Considering removing.)
- In the subclass I create a physics body that has collision, contact, and category bitmasks of UInt32(4), referenced by a static constant from the superclass struct.
- These bodies fall through the ground that is created in the superclass with bitmasks of UInt(2) from the struct property.
- When I change the static constant from UInt(4) to an unsigned int 32 of any odd number between 0 - 32, the bodies do not fall through the ground. Using any even number makes the bodies fall through the ground.

Superclass.swift

```
struct physicsBitMasks {
    static let one = UInt32(1) //for player
    static let two = UInt32(2) //for ground
    static let three = UInt32(3) //for you don't need to know
    static let four = UInt32(4) //for enemy

    ...
    ground.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsBitMasks.one
    ground.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsBitMasks.one
    ground.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = physicsBitMasks.two
}
```

Subclass.swift

```
Subclass: Superclass {
    //create enemy
    thing.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask =  physicsBitMasks.four
    thing.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsBitMasks.four
    thing.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = physicsBitMasks.four
}
```

Enemy falls through ground

REDEFINE
Superclass.swift

```
struct physicsBitMasks {
    static let one = UInt32(1) //for player
    static let two = UInt32(2) //for ground
    static let three = UInt32(3) //for you don't need to know
    static let four = UInt32(5) // or 7, 9, ...31 for enemy
}
```

Enemy does not fall through ground.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't `playerMask`, `groundMask`, `mysteryMask`, and `enemyMask` be better names than `one`, `two`, `three`, and `four`?

Also, because they are bit mask components, you need each to have a single unique bit set. But 3, for example, contains the bits of 1 and 2. Let's define them this way:

```
struct BodyMask {
    static let Player = UInt32(1)
    static let Ground = UInt32(2)
    static let EmbarrassingSecret = UInt32(4)
    static let Enemy = UInt32(8)
}
```

Now you need to set the various masks on your bodies. You should set each's body's `categoryBitMask` to the mask for its type:

```
ground.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyMask.Ground
player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyMask.Player
enemies.forEach { $0.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyMask.Enemy }
twilightNovel.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyMask.EmbarrassingSecret
```

You need to set each body's `collisionBitMask` based on what other bodies you want it to bounce off of. That is, do you want an enemy to bounce off the ground? Then the enemy's `collisionBitMask` must include the `BodyMask.Ground` bit. Do you want the ground to bounce off of an enemy? Or bounce off of anything else? Probably not. Note that this is asymmetric! The enemy can bounce of the ground without the ground bouncing. That is, Newton's third law (for every action there is an equal and opposite reaction) doesn't have to apply.

If you want a body to bounce off of multiple other body types, you can bitwise-or the masks together. Let's assume you want enemies to bounce off of the ground and each other.

```
ground.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyMask.Ground
enemies.forEach { $0.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyMask.Ground | BodyMask.Enemy }
twilightNovel.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyMask.Ground
```

Finally, if you want to be notified when two bodies collide (regardless of whether they bounce), you can use `contactTestBitMask`. You probably want to know when the player touches an enemy, or when the player does something embarrassing, even though you don't necessarily want the player to bounce off of enemies or trashy novels.

```
ground.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0
player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyMask.Enemy | BodyMask.EmbarrassingSecret
enemies.forEach { $0.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0 }
twilightNovel.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0
```

Comment: collision needs binary or, ok. and the collision bitmask is the bitmasks of things it will bounce off of. and those aren't exact names. thanks